# Click event for ItemTemplate inside asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with the following markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvResxKeyValue" runat="server" Width="100%" >
  <Columns>     
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                        
        <asp:Image ID="imgEditResxValue" CssClass="sfEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Administrator/Templates/Default/images/imgedit.png"  />                     
    </ItemTemplate>                              
  </asp:TemplateField>                                       
  </Columns>                                       
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to have a handler for the Image click event. Is there any easier way to do so?

Comment: can't you change your image to ImageButton?

Comment: I am upgrading an already used framework to a newer version. Previously it was handled by javascript using jquery-1.4.4.min.js and 'live('click')' event was handling it but this time 'on' should be used and it is not supporting. I have no authority to change image to imagebutton.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an Image Button instead of Image. Try this code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvResxKeyValue" runat="server" Width="100%" >
  <Columns>     
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                        
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditResxValue" CssClass="sfEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Administrator/Templates/Default/images/imgedit.png" OnClick="YourEventName"  />                     
    </ItemTemplate>                              
  </asp:TemplateField>                                       
  </Columns>                                       
</asp:GridView>
```

You just need to specify your server side event name here.

Answer (score 1):

Use an asp button and set its style to be `display:none`

```
<asp:Image ID="imgEditResxValue" CssClass="sfEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Administrator/Templates/Default/images/imgedit.png" onclick="ClickImage(this)"  />
.......


<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="hiddenButton_Click" style="display:none"></asp:Button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickImage(imageControl)
{
     document.getElementById('<%=hiddenButton.ClientID%>').click();
}
</script>
```

This will raise the server side event of the button and you can do your work there.

Comment: I tried keeping the button within ItemTemplate but while taking document.getElementById('<%=hiddenButton.ClientID%>').click();        error regarding "The name 'hiddenButton' doesnot exists in the current context" arrises while building.

Comment: Keep the button outside the grid view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jquery Solution

```
<asp:Image ID="imgEditResxValue" CssClass="sfEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Administrator/Templates/Default/images/imgedit.png"  onclick="this.next().click()"/>                     
                                            <asp:LinkButton Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="call_method"/>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/170696 BTW, onclick in your answer won't work